# I cant run `start-hbase.cmd` `Error: Could not find or load main class .F` and `ERROR: Could not determine the startup mode`

Tags: cmd.exe

I cant run `start-hbase.cmd`. I was able to run `start-hbase.cmd` yesterday and it worked fine, but now if I run `start-hbase.cmd` I get`Error: Could not find or load main class .F` and `ERROR: Could not determine the startup mode`. I restarted my laptop and still not luck. I tried reinstalling from here and not luck. http://apache.claz.org/hbase/1.2.6/hbase-1.2.6-bin.tar.gz

See following console output.

```
  C:\hbase-1.2.6\bin>start-hbase.cmd
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true\
Error: Could not find or load main class .F
ERROR: Could not determine the startup mode.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was an issue with my Java Arguments.

When I removed the system variable `_JAVA_OPTIONS` which was set to `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true\` the error went away and I was able to start hbase.

What's even more odd is I added the `_JAVA_OPTIONS` back and restarted my laptop. Ran the `start-hbase.cmd` again and it was successful.

If someone could explain this then I will accept that answer. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This might be obvious, but did you walk through the CMD file to make sure you didn't move or rename anything that is related to this new issue?

Depending on the complexity of the CMD file -- this might be easy.

Another possibility is that it's a [path] related issue and it really can't find what it needs to run.  You can still see the [path] in Windows 10 using the [set] statement in a command window.

HTH

Comment: This is hbase out of the box. I have not edited anything.

Comment: I saw your note up above (the IPv4 switch) and I'm guessing this has to do with port binding.  Many RDBMS (and other server-based systems) will bind to a port on an IPv4 internet address.

Comment: Oops - didn't finish up correctly.  I suspect this will happen to you again, but you have an option -- something I recently did in a similar situation.  Configure a loopback adapter and use that IPv4 address for your server.  You'll need to add it to your host file, but it's worth it to keep things consistent on rebooting (esp. if you use DHCP - like I do at home).